# Замена подстроки в регулярных выражениях

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Например, есть строка:

```
$str='abc0|def0ghi0|ghi';
```

Нужно заменить `0`, на `_NULL_`. Но только в тех местах, где `0` внутри вертикальных палок.

То есть, должно получиться `abc0|def_NULL_ghi_NULL_|ghi`

```
preg_replace('/\|(.*)0(.*)\|/U', '$1_NULL_$2', $str);
```

Заменяет всё, что между палок.

Как заменить только нули?

Answer (score 3):

Лучше вначале сделать [split](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.split.php)/[explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) для строки, потом, для всех элементов от 1 до `count(...)-2` сделать нужную замену (а она теперь будет тривиальной) и потом сделать [join](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.join.php).

```
$str = 'abc0|def0ghi0|ghi';
$a = explode('|', $str);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($a)-2; $i++) {
  $a[$i] = str_replace('0', '_NULL_', $a[$i]);
}
$str = join('|', $a);
```

Диапазон такой, что бы не учитывать начальный/конечный элемент.

При желании, можно вместо цикла использовать [array_map](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) или подобное.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае можно обойтись и без регулярного выражения, однако в более трудных случаях, когда необходимо заменить любое число подстрок между двух *одинаковых* подстрок, можно воспользоваться функцией [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php) и простой регуляркой типа `/DELIM1(.*?)DELIM2/s`, а внутри анонимной функции обратного вызова можно будет произвести любые необходимые манипуляции с совпадением:

```
$delim = '|';
$s = 'abc0|def0ghi0|ghi';
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/(' . preg_quote($delim, '/') . ')(.*?)(' . preg_quote($delim, '/') . ')/s',
    function($m) { return $m[1] . str_replace('0', '', $m[2]) . $m[3]; },
    $s);
// => abc0|defghi|ghi
```

См. [PHP-демо](http://ideone.com/rE4cpF)

- `preg_quote($delim, '/')` - экранирует все специальные знаки в `$delim`
- `/\|(.*?)\|/s` - этот шаблон находит буквальный символ `|`, любые 0 и более знаков, однако как можно меньше, и затем снова `|`
- `$m[1]` – это значение первой захватывающей подмаски (группы), `$m[2]` – второй и т.д.

Конечно, можно в данном случае заменить `.*?` более эффективным исключающим символьным классом `[^|]` (= любой символ кроме `|`).

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример замены нулей с помощью регулярного выражения и функции `preg_replace_callback`.

Это работающая регулярка:

```
#\|[^\|0]*((0)[^\|]*)*\|#m
```

Вот измененная строка автора:

```
$str = 'abc0|def0ghi0fd0dfdsf0|ghi|sdfdf0sdfdf0sdfds|sdfd';
```

Это код `php` дает нам нужный ответ в виде измененной строки:

```
<?php
    $str = 'abc0|def0ghi0fd0dfdsf0|ghi|sdfdf0sdfdf0sdfds|sdfd';
    $str = preg_replace_callback('#\|[^\|0]*((0)[^\|]*)*\|#m', function($matches){
        return str_replace('0','_NULL_', $matches[0]);
    }, $str);
    echo $str;
?>
```

А это пример самого ответа:

`abc0|def_NULL_ghi_NULL_fd_NULL_dfdsf_NULL_|ghi|sdfdf_NULL_sdfdf_NULL_sdfds|sdfd`

Comment: согласен - моё решение было не универсальное, удалил.